# Create product custom image attribute module in magento2.1.9

Tags: magento2, attributes

How to write the custom image attribute I do not know please help me out. I used below code but in backend form field showing but image functionality not working.

In `product_form.php`:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="file_uploader_attribute_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Slider Images</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="custom_image2">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <!--                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>-->
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Image2</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="module/catelog_image/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="custom_image1">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <!--                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>-->
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Image1</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="module/catelog_image/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And `installData.php` used this code:

```
<?php

namespace Rokanthemes\ImageSliding\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory /* For Attribute create  */;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $_eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */
         $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'custom_image1', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'backend' => 'Rokanthemes\ImageSliding\Model\Attribute\Product\Image', //'Rokanthemes\ImageSliding\Model\Attribute\Product\Image',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'custom image1',
            'input' => 'image',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
                ]
        );
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'custom_image2', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'backend' => 'Rokanthemes\ImageSliding\Model\Attribute\Product\Image', //'Rokanthemes\ImageSliding\Model\Attribute\Product\Image',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'custom image2',
            'input' => 'image',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
                ]
        );
    }

}
```

Please help me. Very new to Magento

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `varchar` to `file`:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'custom_image1', [
        'type' => 'file',
        'backend' => 'Rokanthemes\ImageSliding\Model\Attribute\Product\Image', //'Rokanthemes\ImageSliding\Model\Attribute\Product\Image',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'custom image1',
        'input' => 'image',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => 0,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => ''
            ]
    );
```